# custom program error: 0x64:

Tags: solana-program, rust, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm facing an issue while breeding the NFTs. The first test case for initializing the parent and the second test case for computing the child run successfully. This means that the child generation is created successfully. However, when the 'mint NFT' test case runs, it shows an error.
I'd following this repo to breed the NFT
https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding

I thought the issue occurred in the Utils file, ATA_PROGRAM_ID
https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding/blob/master/ts/utils.ts

What address should I replace with this ATA_INIT_PROGRAM_ID address?

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::{hash, Hash};

use anchor_lang::solana_program::{system_program, sysvar::slot_hashes};
use anchor_spl::associated_token::get_associated_token_address;
use anchor_spl::token::{
    self, Burn, CloseAccount, InitializeMint, Mint, SetAuthority, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer,
};

use anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke;
use mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator;
declare_id!("Eufn4X2tiH33jFaYLy4JzPZ4bCywLJ12YEvkMD16qZoL");

#[program]
pub mod nft_breeding {

    use anchor_lang::solana_program::{native_token::Sol, program::invoke_signed};
    use mpl_token_metadata::{instruction::update_metadata_accounts_v2, state::DataV2};

    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        bump: u8,
        name: Vec<u8>,
        symbol: Vec<u8>,
        attributes: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        //generate hash
        let mut hash_data: Vec<u8> = ctx.accounts.authority.key().to_bytes().clone().to_vec();
        hash_data.append(&mut ctx.accounts.token_mint.key().to_bytes().clone().to_vec());
        hash_data.append(&mut system_program::id().to_bytes().clone().to_vec());
        hash_data.append(&mut system_program::id().to_bytes().clone().to_vec());
        hash_data.append(&mut name.clone());
        hash_data.append(&mut symbol.clone());
        for mut attribute in attributes.clone() {
            hash_data.append(&mut attribute);
        }

        let hash_value = hash_to_fix_len(&hash_data);

        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.hash = hash_value;
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.generation = 0;
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.authority = ctx.accounts.authority.key().clone();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.mint = ctx.accounts.token_mint.key().clone();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.parent_a = system_program::id();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.parent_b = system_program::id();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.name = name.clone();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.symbol = symbol.clone();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.attributes = attributes.clone();
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.breeding = false;
        ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.bump = bump;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn compute(ctx: Context<Compute>, bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        //decide new attributes
        let mut random_seed: Vec<u8> = vec![0];
        random_seed.extend_from_slice(
            &ctx.accounts
                .parent_a_breeding_meta
                .to_account_info()
                .data
                .borrow(),
        );
        random_seed.extend_from_slice(
            &ctx.accounts
                .parent_b_breeding_meta
                .to_account_info()
                .data
                .borrow(),
        );
        random_seed.extend_from_slice(
            &ctx.accounts
                .slot_hashes_account
                .to_account_info()
                .data
                .borrow(),
        );
        let random = hash(&random_seed).to_bytes().to_vec();
        let mut new_attributes: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![];

        // hash length is 32 bytes long
        // Support up to 32 attributes in metadata
        for index in 0..ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.attributes.len() {
            if random[index] % 2 == 0 {
                new_attributes.push(ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.attributes[index].clone())
            }
            if random[index] % 2 == 1 {
                new_attributes.push(ctx.accounts.parent_b_breeding_meta.attributes[index].clone())
            }
        }

        //generate hash

        let mut hash_data: Vec<u8> = ctx
            .accounts
            .parent_a_breeding_meta
            .authority
            .to_bytes()
            .clone()
            .to_vec();
        hash_data.append(&mut ctx.accounts.new_token.key().to_bytes().clone().to_vec());
        hash_data.append(
            &mut ctx
                .accounts
                .parent_a_breeding_meta
                .mint
                .to_bytes()
                .clone()
                .to_vec(),
        );
        hash_data.append(
            &mut ctx
                .accounts
                .parent_b_breeding_meta
                .mint
                .to_bytes()
                .clone()
                .to_vec(),
        );
        hash_data.append(&mut ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.name.clone());
        hash_data.append(&mut ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.symbol.clone());
        for mut attribute in new_attributes.clone() {
            hash_data.append(&mut attribute);
        }
        let hash_value = hash_to_fix_len(&hash_data);
        let generation = ctx
            .accounts
            .parent_a_breeding_meta
            .generation
            .max(ctx.accounts.parent_b_breeding_meta.generation)
            .checked_add(1)
            .unwrap();
        ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.breeding = true;
        ctx.accounts.parent_b_breeding_meta.breeding = true;

        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.hash = hash_value.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.generation = generation.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.mint = ctx.accounts.new_token.key().clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.authority =
            ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.authority.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.parent_a =
            ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.mint.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.parent_b =
            ctx.accounts.parent_b_breeding_meta.mint.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.name = ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.name.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.symbol =
            ctx.accounts.parent_a_breeding_meta.symbol.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.attributes = new_attributes.clone();
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.breeding = true;
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.bump = bump;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn mint(ctx: Context<MintChild>) -> Result<()> {
        let creators = Creator {
            share: 100,
            address: ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.key(),
            verified: false,
        };
        let create_metadata_ins = mpl_token_metadata::instruction::create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            mpl_token_metadata::ID,
            ctx.accounts.new_token_metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_token.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.key(),
            String::from_utf8(ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.name.clone()).unwrap(),
            String::from_utf8(ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.symbol.clone()).unwrap(),
            "".to_string(),
            Some(vec![creators]),
            1,
            true,
            false,
            None,
            None,
            None,
        );
        invoke(&create_metadata_ins, &ctx.accounts.to_account_infos())?;
        let master_edition_ix = mpl_token_metadata::instruction::create_master_edition_v3(
            mpl_token_metadata::ID,
            ctx.accounts.new_token_master_edition.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_token.key(),
            ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_token_metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            None,
        );
        invoke_signed(
            &master_edition_ix,
            &ctx.accounts.to_account_infos(),
            &[&[
                b"breeding",
                &ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.authority.key().to_bytes(),
                &ctx.accounts.new_token.key().to_bytes(),
                &ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.bump.to_le_bytes(),
            ]],
        )?;
        anchor_spl::token::burn(ctx.accounts.burn_parent_a_token_from_owner(), 1)?;
        anchor_spl::token::burn(ctx.accounts.burn_parent_b_token_from_owner(), 1)?;
        ctx.accounts.child_breeding_meta.breeding = false;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_uri(ctx: Context<UpdateUri>, uri: String) -> Result<()> {
        let creators = Creator {
            share: 100,
            address: ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.key(),
            verified: false,
        };
        let update_ix = update_metadata_accounts_v2(
            mpl_token_metadata::ID,
            ctx.accounts.nft_metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.key(),
            None,
            Some(DataV2 {
                name: String::from_utf8(ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.hash.to_vec()).unwrap(),
                symbol: "".to_string(),
                uri: uri,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                collection: None,
                creators: Some(vec![creators]),
                uses: None,
            }),
            Some(false),
            Some(true),
        );
        invoke_signed(
            &update_ix,
            &ctx.accounts.to_account_infos(),
            &[&[
                b"breeding",
                &ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.authority.key().to_bytes(),
                &ctx.accounts.nft_mint.key().to_bytes(),
                &ctx.accounts.breeding_meta.bump.to_le_bytes(),
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    pub token_metadata: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"breeding".as_ref(),&authority.key().as_ref(), &token_mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 1000
    )]
    pub breeding_meta: Account<'info, BreedingMeta>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Compute<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_token: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"breeding".as_ref(),&parent_a_breeding_meta.authority.key().as_ref(), &new_token.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        space = 1000
    )]
    pub child_breeding_meta: Account<'info, BreedingMeta>,
    #[account(
        constraint = parent_a_token_account.owner == payer.key(),
        constraint = parent_a_token_account.mint == parent_a_breeding_meta.mint,
        constraint = parent_a_token_account.amount > 0,
    )]
    pub parent_a_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(mut,
        constraint = parent_a_breeding_meta.authority == parent_b_breeding_meta.authority,
        constraint = parent_a_breeding_meta.breeding == false,
        constraint = parent_a_breeding_meta.name == parent_b_breeding_meta.name,
        constraint = parent_a_breeding_meta.symbol == parent_b_breeding_meta.symbol
    )]
    pub parent_a_breeding_meta: Account<'info, BreedingMeta>,
    #[account(
        constraint = parent_b_token_account.owner == payer.key(),
        constraint = parent_b_token_account.mint == parent_b_breeding_meta.mint,
        constraint = parent_b_token_account.amount > 0
    )]
    pub parent_b_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(mut,
        constraint = parent_b_breeding_meta.breeding == false
    )]
    pub parent_b_breeding_meta: Account<'info, BreedingMeta>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    #[account(
        constraint = slot_hashes_account.key() == slot_hashes::id()
    )]
    pub slot_hashes_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintChild<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_token: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_token_metadata: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    #[account(mut)]
    pub new_token_master_edition: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub child_breeding_meta: Account<'info, BreedingMeta>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub parent_a_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub parent_a_token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub parent_b_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub parent_b_token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    pub token_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    pub metadata_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
impl<'info> MintChild<'info> {
    fn burn_parent_a_token_from_owner(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Burn<'info>> {
        let cpi_accounts = Burn {
            mint: self.parent_a_token_mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            from: self.parent_a_token_account.to_account_info().clone(),
            authority: self.payer.to_account_info().clone(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(self.token_program.clone(), cpi_accounts)
    }
    fn burn_parent_b_token_from_owner(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Burn<'info>> {
        let cpi_accounts = Burn {
            mint: self.parent_b_token_mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            from: self.parent_b_token_account.to_account_info().clone(),
            authority: self.payer.to_account_info().clone(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(self.token_program.clone(), cpi_accounts)
    }
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateUri<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut,
        constraint = breeding_meta.mint == nft_account.mint,
    )]
    pub breeding_meta: Account<'info, BreedingMeta>,
    #[account(mut,
        constraint = owner.key() == nft_account.owner,
        constraint = nft_account.amount > 0
    )]
    pub nft_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    #[account(mut)]
    pub nft_metadata: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    pub metadata_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
#[account]
pub struct BreedingMeta {
    pub hash: [u8; 32],
    pub generation: u8,
    pub mint: Pubkey,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub parent_a: Pubkey,
    pub parent_b: Pubkey,
    pub name: Vec<u8>,
    pub symbol: Vec<u8>,
    pub attributes: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
    pub breeding: bool,
    pub bump: u8,
}

pub fn hash_to_fix_len(hash_data: &Vec<u8>) -> [u8; 32] {
    let encoded = hex::encode(hash(hash_data));
    let src = encoded.as_bytes();
    let mut hash_value = [0u8; 32];
    hash_value[..].copy_from_slice(&src[..32]);
    hash_value
}
```

Comment: i think it's not related to an account in particular. error 0x64 is error 100 in decimal, and it means that there is a problem with your instruction discriminator. could you show us your code please ?

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. You can check now the MintNFT part.

Comment: do you have a tx signature, in order that i can check logs ?

Comment: @Effe2 - The transaction can't be completed as I run test cases. You can check the complete rust program I just edited.

Comment: ok thanks for editing, i may need a last thing (hope so!), could you also share the code you use to call your program ? (js code)

Comment: @Effe2 -  Yes, but the code has been written across 3 to 4 files. It might be an issue to paste it all here I guess. You can check the repo, hope it will clear you.
https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding/blob/master/tests/nft-breeding.ts

Comment: @Effe2 -  I commented all the mint function codes while running testcase of the minting child and showed the same error
custom program error: 0x64:

Comment: i'm checking your code on github, do you have a stack trace with the error ?

Comment: Thanks for checking, 
Yes I check but don't get much info regarding to error

Comment: but in your stack trace, you don't have the line where the error originated from ? (because it could be in any test...)

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand stack trace, basically I'm new in Rust so that's why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148784/discussion-between-effe2-and-umaid-khalid).